# wget does not download all images

Tags: download, cron, wget

Good morning,
every day I have to save images from a web page which is updated daily.

To do this I use the wget command, but unfortunately on about 2000 images I download about 1000 and then it stops.

The command I use is:
wget -nc -i URL_DOWNLOAD -P PATH_IMAGE

I use -nc to ensure that already downloaded images are not re-downloaded again.

Am I wrong something?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough space ? what is the error ?

Comment: no no, there is space ...

Comment: How do you do the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

> I use the wget command, but unfortunately on about 2000 images I
> download about 1000 and then it stops.
>
> The command I use is: wget -nc -i URL_DOWNLOAD -P PATH_IMAGE

You have probably hit rate limit of server. Some servers if you are making too much requests in given time unit (e.g. minute) might gently inform you that you should not using [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) response or refuse to provide response altogether. Inspect `wget`'s stderr to find what happend exactly.

You might try using `--wait=` option to avoid that, from [`wget` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

> --wait=seconds
> Wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals. Use of this option is recommended, as it lightens the server load by
> making the requests less frequent. Instead of in seconds, the time can
> be specified in minutes using the "m" suffix, in hours using "h"
> suffix, or in days using "d" suffix.

but you would need to find value acceptable for you yourself, example usage: waiting 3 seconds after each download

```
wget --wait=3 -nc -i URL_DOWNLOAD -P PATH_IMAGE
```

Note that for 2000 urls this would require at least 100 minutes.